# Laravel - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am building a project in Laravel on trying to persist a record in the database for the model Content that I have set up like this:

```
class Content extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are guarded by mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function contentType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ContentType');
    }
}
```

In my controller I am first saving the record in the content_types table like this:

```
    public function resolveType($type)
    {
        return ContentType::firstOrCreate(
          ['name' => $type,
          'slug' => str_slug($type, '-')]
        );
    }
```

And then I am saving the content:

```
        Content::create([
          'ct_id' => $post->ID,
          'cms_id' => '',
          'title' => $post->post_title,
          'slug' => str_slug($post->post_title, '-'),
          'excerpt' => $post->post_excerpt,
          'body' => $this->formatBodyImages($post->post_content),
          'password' => $post->post_password,
          'parent_id' => $post->post_parent,
        ]);
```

The ContentType model is set up like this:

```
class ContentType extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are guarded by mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [
        'id'
    ];

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Content', 'ct_id');
    }
}
```

So, when I try to persist new content record, I get the error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`middleton`.`contents`, CONSTRAINT `contents_ct_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`ct_id`) REFERENCES `content_types` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into
>   `contents` (`cms_id`, `title`, `slug`, `excerpt`, `body`, `password`,
>   `parent_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)

Comment: It basically says that the value for *ct_id* does not exist in the *content_types* table and you have a foreign key to relate these two. Can you **var_dump** `$post->ID` and confirm you have this value in the table before trying to create a new *Content* record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$post->ID` is empty and there is `ContentType` with specified ID in the DB. Maybe you're trying to do this?

```
'ct_id' => $post->id,
```

You can check contents of the `$post` variable with `dd($post)` command.

If `$post->id` gives you correct value (it's not empty and it exists in the table), then try to use `fillable` array with all listed properties of using `guarded` array.